# How to remove gap between bars in multi bar char in in chart js (react js )

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-3sxjj?file=/src/index.js:1361-1476
How to remove the gap between bars of bar chart..as shown in the code sand box link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set barPercentage and categoryPercentage to `1`;

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var chart  = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        type: "bar",
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                barPercentage: 1,
                categoryPercentage: 1
            }]
        }
    },
    data: {
      labels: ["January", "February"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Total trolley handled",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          borderWidth: 1,
          //stack: 1,
          hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
          hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          data: [1559, 1174]
        },

        {
          label: "Total trolley handled",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(155,231,91,0.2)",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          borderWidth: 1,
          //stack: 1,
          hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
          hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          data: [1785, 1353]
        }
      ]
    }
});
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <div class="text-center">
        <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-z07im?file=/src/index.js)